# on import vue-collage-slideshow nuxt is giving me error 'document is not defined'

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to import [vue-collage-slideshow](https://github.com/edicasoft/vue-collage-slideshow) in nuxt to make a gallery slideshow in my project , but it is giving me an error, Please any help will be highly appreciated.
the code is given below

```html
<template>
  <div id="collage">
    <client-only placeholder="Loading...">
      <slideshow
        :images="images"
        :collage-size-min="5"
        :collage-size-max="5"
        :slides-interval="4000"
        :show-no-images-msg="true"
        no-images-msg="No Images"
        :show-loading-msg="true"
        loading-msg="Loading..."
        height="100%"
      >
      </slideshow>
    </client-only>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Slideshow from 'vue-collage-slideshow'

export default {
  name: 'Collage',
  components: {
    Slideshow,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      images: [
        { image: 'https://wallpapershome.com/images/pages/pic_v/5111.jpg' },
        {
          image:
            'https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/1280x868/https%3A%2F%2Fblogs-images.forbes.com%2Fannabel%2Ffiles%2F2018%2F02%2FLouisville_Skyline-1200x801.jpg',
        },
        { image: 'https://t-ec.bstatic.com/images/hotel/max1024x768/683/68345284.jpg' },
        { image: 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/08/ec/94/08ec94ecf38048a2102ec4783dc88fa8.jpg' },
        { image: 'https://t-ec.bstatic.com/images/hotel/max1024x768/873/87316855.jpg' },
      ],
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: maybe that package is not designed to use in Nuxt, try any other packages.

Comment: thank you @kissu for your kind response .. I tried but it didn't work for me, so I had to go with another approach.

Comment: I don't understand what is not working, nor the error. I only saw a 404. If you fix it, everything should be working. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is totally fine and everything is working as expected, you only need to fix the broken URL:
https://t-ec.bstatic.com/images/hotel/max1024x768/683/68345284.jpg

Hence the `404` error

[image]